# Prove that the $j$-th column of $AB$ is the product $Ab_j$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that the $j$-th column of $AB$ is the product of $A$ and the $j$-th column of $B$

First of all, **THIS IS NOT HOMEWORK**. This **was** a homework.

I can prove this using the fact that $e_j$ extracts the $j$-th column of a matrix.
$$(AB)e_j=A(Be_j)=Ab_j$$
However, I'd like a proof using the definition of matrix multiplication (i.e $(AB)_{ij}=$$\sum\limits_k {{a_i}_k{b_k}_j}$)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$(Ab_j)_i = \sum_k a_{ik} (b_j)_k = \sum_k a_{ik} b_{kj} = (AB)_{ij}.$$

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I tried to do it myself but I was not satisfied with my notation.